# Order of opening named pipes causing possible race condition?

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to create a very basic client server communication between two processes using IPC via named pipes.

I have 2 pipes, namely `fifo_client` and `fifo_server`

I have the following two classes `fifoclient.c` and `fifoserver.c` that has the following lines of code to open the two pipes.

`fifoclient.c`

```
int client = open("fifo_client",O_WRONLY);
int server = open("fifo_server",O_RDONLY);
```

`fifoserver.c`

```
int client = open("fifo_client",O_RDONLY);
int server = open("fifo_server",O_WRONLY);
```

However, on simply changing the order of opening the `client` and `server` pipes in `fifoserver.c`, the program freezes.

This is how the code is written when it freezes:

`fifoserver.c`

```
int server = open("fifo_server",O_WRONLY);
int client = open("fifo_client",O_RDONLY);
```

Notice that the `server` pipe is opened before the `client` pipe in this case. This leads to the program not responding (possible race condition?).

Can someone explain what is happening and why?

EDIT:

Here's the entire code for both the classes:

`fifoserver.c`

```
#define BUFSIZE 20
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main()
{

    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int client = open("fifo_client",O_RDONLY);
    int server = open("fifo_server",O_WRONLY);
    if( server<0 || client < 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    read(client,buf,BUFSIZE*sizeof(char));
    printf("Client Says: %s\n",buf);
    write(server,"Fine, Thank You!",BUFSIZE*sizeof(char));
    close(server);
    close(client);      
    return 0;
}
```

`fifoclient.c`

```
#define BUFSIZE 20
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int client = open("fifo_client",O_WRONLY);
    int server = open("fifo_server",O_RDONLY);
    if(client <0 || server <0)
    {
         printf("ERROR! Couldn't open file!\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    write(client,"Hello! How are you?",BUFSIZE*sizeof(char));
    read(server,buf,BUFSIZE*sizeof(char));
    printf("Server Says: %s\n",buf);
    close(server);
    close(client);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the code in the two files, but I am guessing that the client and server expect their connection handshake to happen in a certain order.

Comment: You're using blocking `open`, `read` and `write`, so the order of calling matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man 7 fifo`:

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for  each  FIFO  special  file  that  is
>   opened  by  at  least one process.  The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and
>   writing) before data can be passed.  Normally, opening  the  FIFO  blocks  until  the
>   other end is opened also.

In other words, your `open()` call will block until there is a process on the other end of the pipe.  This is not a race condition -- rather, it is a deadlock.  If the processes do not open the pipes in the same order, they will wait forever on one another. So, as you noticed, the solution is that they must both open the fifos in the same order.

Answer (score 4):

> fifoclient.c
>
> ```
> int client = open("fifo_client",O_WRONLY);
> ```

This open in the client will block until the FIFO is opened for reading.

> fifoserver.c
>
> ```
> int client = open("fifo_client",O_RDONLY);
> ```

This open, in the server, will unblock the previous open in the client.

Now, when you swap the lines in the server to look like

> ```
> int server = open("fifo_server",O_WRONLY);
> int client = open("fifo_client",O_RDONLY);
> ```

the client is blocked opening the client FIFO but the server is trying to open the server FIFO for writing (which will block until somebody opens it for reading). None of them can proceed to the line which will unblock the other.

Comment: Thanks that explained a lot. So it seems that the second code falls victim to a classic case of a deadlock.